# discord.embed update with role reaction

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to update a discord.embed with reaction:

```
@bot.command()
async def expedition(ctx, expe, date, heure):
    embed=discord.Embed(title="Expedition", description= expe + "\n" + date + " : " + heure + "\nFor " + ctx.message.author.mention, color=0xFF5733)
    embed.add_field(name="tank", value="1 slots", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="heal", value="1 slots", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="dps", value="3 slots", inline=True)
    msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await msg.add_reaction('\N{SHIELD}')
    await msg.add_reaction('‍⚕️')
    await msg.add_reaction('\N{CROSSED SWORDS}')
    await msg.add_reaction('❌')

    @client.event
    async def on_raw_reaction_add(reaction,user):
        if reaction.emoji == '\N{SHIELD}':
            embed.set_field_at(0,name="tank",value=user.mention)
            print("test 1")
        if reaction.emoji == '‍⚕️':
            embed.set_field_at(1,name="heal",value=user)
            print("2 test")
        if reaction.emoji == '\N{CROSSED SWORDS}':
            embed.set_field_at(2,name="dps",value=user)
            print("D la réponse D")
```

I create a discord embed with some default information, and add the reaction I want to use,
the idea is that when someone react with one of the select reaction, the name of the user is added to the field.

( I actually have 4 commands using the same "template" with the same reaction, and I want them all to work individually)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `wait_for` for this.

Also `on_raw_reaction_add` takes only one argument that is `payload`, I believe you are trying to use `on_reaction_add`

Remove the while loop if you wish to consider only the first reaction that is added

```py
async def expedition(ctx, expe, date, heure):
    embed=discord.Embed(title="Expedition", description= expe + "\n" + date + " : " + heure + "\nFor " + ctx.message.author.mention, color=0xFF5733)
    embed.add_field(name="tank", value="1 slots", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="heal", value="1 slots", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="dps", value="3 slots", inline=True)
    msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await msg.add_reaction('\N{SHIELD}')
    await msg.add_reaction('‍⚕️')
    await msg.add_reaction('\N{CROSSED SWORDS}')
    await msg.add_reaction('❌')

    while True:
        reaction, user = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", check=lambda reaction, user: reaction.message.id == msg.id)
        if reaction.emoji == '\N{SHIELD}':
            embed.set_field_at(0,name="tank",value=user.mention)
            print("test 1")
        if reaction.emoji == '‍⚕️':
            embed.set_field_at(1,name="heal",value=user)
            print("2 test")
        if reaction.emoji == '\N{CROSSED SWORDS}':
            embed.set_field_at(2,name="dps",value=user)
            print("D la réponse D")
```

Comment: thakns for you'r answer, when I try you'r code it return : 

```reaction, user = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", check=lambda reaction, user: reaction.message.id == msg.id)
AttributeError: module 'discord.client' has no attribute 'wait_for' ```

Comment: Nevermind, it work just fine, client == bot on my code, thanks a lot :D

Comment: @Ashuni If this answer resolved your problem, then please consider [accepting it as the answer to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), by clicking the checkmark to the left and/or up-voting it by clicking the up arrow in the same area. (See [What does it mean to accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for information) This lets others know the problem has been solved.